# How to prevent the 3CX chrome extension from making a number clickable

Tags: 3cx

At our company, we use chrome and have the [3CX chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/3cx/baipgmmeifmofkcilhccccoipmjccehn?hl=en).

This extension is quite eager to transform any sequence of number into a clickable link to pass a phone call.

How to prevent the 3CX extension from converting sequences of numbers into clickable links on specific pages ?

So far we figured out that enclosing numbers in a `<pre>` or `<code>` tag does the trick. But we need something to disable 3CX as a whole on a webpage.

Does a special meta tag exists for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

So I ran into the same problem my company uses 3cx extension, but it keeps modifying our page to add "click to call" links where it shouldn't.

I found this thread on the official forum which says that apparently they have no options to force the extension to ignore a specific website or field:
https://www.3cx.com/community/threads/disable-the-chrome-extension-for-my-website.79302/

But on the bright side, I implemented a hack on my field to force the extension to ignore numbers on my string, I added `zero-width space` after each number like this:

`str.split(/(\d+)/g).join('​<zero-width-space>​​​​​​​​​​​​');`​​

the editor does not let me paste the code for the `zero-width space`, it can be acquired here: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/AwVNjg%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Admin Panel>Extensions>Click to Talk> untick the box labeled "Click2Talk"at the top of the page.

Comment: wouldn't that disable the clickable links on all websites ?

Comment: Yes it would. 
You are asking how to make the numbers appear clickable but on certain websites, that you control, not clickable?

Comment: that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: You may be able to disable 3cx from activating on your page. I have not tried this but it looks promising.
Check out http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/02/intro-to-chrome-addons-hacking.html